# What am I failing to understand about a light in a material?

Tags: visible-light, photons, refraction, frequency, wavelength

In a material, a photon's velocity becomes slower, photon's wavelength becomes shorter, but photon's frequency doesn't change.

If there is a material that makes low frequency photons have very short wavelength photons, and if I stick my finger in the material, do I get a radiation burn?  What kind of effects can I have from the short wavelength photons in a material except for the refraction?

Answer (score 6):

The energy of a photon is related to its frequency. In vacuum you can convert freely between frequency and wavelength - but once you have a material with a high refractive index, it's not so simple.

Your question about "radiation burn" is assuming that the energy of a short wavelength photon is always higher. That's not the case. The thing about the photon that doesn't change with medium is the frequency - and that is the thing you need to look at.

Comment: lets assume that i dunk the whole photoelectric effect setup in the material (low freq and short wavelength-ed), am i gonna see the electrons coming out?  my answer will be no, because the low freq was  used not to  cause the photoelectric effect as an initial condition , but this short wavelength that is more than to cause the photo electric effect lingers in  my mind.  any wild guesses are fine and appreciated.

Comment: Photoelectric effect depends on energy not wavelength. Since the usual setup have the cathode in a vacuum that distinction is easily lost. The answer to your hypothetical question: if no electrons would be emitted without dunking the setup in this magical material, the dunking won't change that.

Comment: Comments are like that. PE effect depends on energy, not wavelength.

Comment: why does the linefeed not work by pressing the enter key, it goes striaght to posting.......                       photoelectric effect completly depends on freq or wavelength and not  just on the low freq form of energy.................. my wild guess  was that the material captures  low freq photons and keeps adding (photon spin angular momentum is conserved  to make transition from l=0 to l =1000000 ), and then a material spits out as 1 big shortwavelength photon (providing that spin thing  is still conserved or make it), my wild guess stops here, i will not bother you for this.

Answer (score 2):

> In a material, a photon's velocity becomes slower, photon's wavelength becomes shorter, but photon's frequency doesn't change.

The photon always travels with velocity c and its frequency and wavelength are fixed unless there are inelastic interactions.

The classical wave emerges from a confluence of photons, and it is the classical electromagnetic wave that goes with smaller than c velocity in transparent materials. Because of the way the classical [em wave emerges](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) from the constituent photons  one can qualitatively say that in a transparent material the photons scatter elastically and travel a longer path than the optical ray defining  the light they build up.

This makes no sense "If there is a material that makes low frequency photons have very short wavelength photons".

Low frequency has large wavelengths, period, by construction.

A light beam can give up all its energy, photons included,  to some solid, laser light can melt metals, and yes , your finger will be burned , but that has nothing to do with the original photons' frequency, except the delivery of so much energy that the metal can melt.